# How to make Console.Clear clear all except one specific line? (c#)

Tags: c#

How to make Console.Clear clear all except one specific line? (c#)

So, as a title says i want to clear the whole console except one specific line using c#. Is it possible?

Comment: can you reprint the line?

Comment: One way of achieving this is to pinvoke [FillConsoleOutputCharacter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682663%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, yes, it's possible. But it's not especially easy. You'll have to become familiar with the [Console API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682010(v=vs.85).aspx), including how to call those functions with .NET. Then, what you can do:

1. Locate the line you want to save. If you know where it is on the screen, then it's easy to locate in the console screen buffer.
2. Call [FillConsoleOutputCharacter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682663(v=vs.85).aspx) to output spaces from the start of the screen buffer up to the first character of the line that you want to save.
3. Call `FillConsoleOutputCharacter` again to output spaces from the end of the line you want to save up to the end of the buffer.

I wrote a series of articles about accessing the console from C# a few years back. The articles are no longer online, but the code is available from http://mischel.com/pubs/consoledotnet.zip. You might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. just use this code...

```
string line = yourlinenottobedeleted;
console.clear();
console.WriteLine(line);
```

And the deed is done
(if the line that is not to be deleted is not a string, then put int instead of string)

Comment: just find a way to put it into a variable. and re-print it